# Alterar documento após o middleware post-save no mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

Estou trabalhando com o [mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) e estou precisando que, após salvar o documento na base de dados, eu consiga alterar um atributo daquele documento. Pelo que eu entendi na própria documentação do mongoose, eu percebi que eu poderia fazer isso usando um middleware no schema.

> **NOTA:** preciso definir isso diretamente no meu schema, porque essa manipulação faz parte da regra de negócio da aplicação portanto NÂO tem sentido executar 2 consultas à base de dados.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// schema exemplo
var FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foo: string,
    bar: string
});

// middleware exemplo
FooSchema.post('save', function(doc){
    doc.update({ _id: doc._id}, { $set: { bar:'bar'} }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});

// criando a coleção na base de dados
var FooModel = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema, 'Foo');

// salvando um documento de exemplo
var teste = new FooModel({foo:'foo', bar:'foo'});
teste.save();
```

O que estou precisando fazer é que após o documento ser salvo no banco, eu possa manipular dados diretamente pela regra de negócio já registrada no middleware.

Isso será usado para data mining, portanto em certos casos existem tratamentos que devem ser feitos...

Há alguma forma de manipular o documento após salvá-lo, através de um middleware? Teoricamente o código acima me permite fazer isso, mas não funciona. Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

voce pode tentar fazer um  pre update  no final do seu documento:

```
FooSchema.pre('update', function() {  
     this.update({ _id: this._id},{$set: { bar:'bar'} });
});
```

espero que ajude.